# GWT application "invite friends from Facebook" dialog

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform

I am creating an web application with **java**, GWT-Platform and GAE.
I succeeded to create a "log in with Facebook account" flow, and now i want to create on one of my presenters an "invite friends from Facebook" window that will look like this:
[Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/multi_request_dialog.png/) (*the forum didn't allowed me to attach an image :(* )

I don't want to use any written library like "gwt-facebook", I want to use only Facebook Graph API.
**Is there a way to do it with Java and GWT, and how?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me" site. Make an attempt, then if you get stuck, ask here about the specific line of code that isn't working (for example)

Comment: Look i tried to look on google, and stackoverflow, but i found nothing that i can implement in my java GWT application. Moreover there is no good documentation on Facebook Developers. I can continue to search the web for weeks, but if someone can give me a reference to a good example or to a good guide, it can me save me a lot of time, and for him it is several minutes of answer... Don't you think it should be like that?

Comment: Try asking on a GWT-specific forum, like [google's GWT discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/topics?pli=1) or the [GWT forum at coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/forums/f-99/GWT)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used GWT but I've worked on something similar. Can't you generate custom javascript on the page that gets generated and use the Facebook javascript SDK to do this?